# Enable notifications for some emails in gmail application on Android

Tags: applications, gmail, push-notifications

I am not sure this is good place for this question, if not, if you could please route me to right page.

So the thing is, I have android phone, and I have GMail account, and application GMail installed on my phone. I get notifications but only for mail that is arriving in Primary Inbox.

Since I am programmer and I have my team on my job and we are using GitHub, and any time someone changes something in the project I get email notifications. But, this email notifications goes into Forum section, and I do not get notification on my phone?

Is there any way I can change settings so that emails from GitHub still get into Forum section but for me to get push notification of GMail application informing me I have new email from GitHub...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable notifications for Forum emails, follow the steps below:

Open Gmail → open the menu on the top left → settings → youraccount@Gmail.com → manage labels → forums → label notifications "on", notify for every message "on".

You should now be getting notifications for those emails.

Comment: Oh I see, I can as well create new label only for GitHub and get notifications only for those emails, as I do not want to get notifications for all messages that arrives in Forum section, thanks

Comment: Also if I create a filter for messages on gmail that will star email from GitHub, then they will arrive to Primary Inbox

Comment: I'm not sure if your asking or saying. I didn't really experiment too much with staring emails, so I can't weigh in

Comment: I am saying, that is what I discovered when I tried to create GitHub label